# Is there a practical use for the GNU factor command?

Tags: command, gnu, coreutils

Looking through the [GNU Coreutils](http://www.catonmat.net/download/gnu-coreutils-cheat-sheet.pdf), I spotted the `factor` command, that I had never noticed before.

Reading the man page:

> Print the prime factors of each specified integer NUMBER.  If none
>   are specified on the command line, read them from standard input.

Is there a practical use for `factor`, or is it just a demonstration / toy package?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Wikipedia, "Factor (Unix)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_(Unix)) with an interesting take:

> factor first appeared on 5th edition Research Unix in 1974, as a "user maintained" utility (section 6 of the manual). In the 7th edition in 1979, it was moved into the main "commands" section of the manual (section 1). From there, the factor utility was copied to all other variants of Unix, including commercial Unixes and BSD. In some variants of Unix, it is classified as a "game" more than a serious utility, and therefore documented in section 6.

So it would seem that some user(s) liked to play around with prime factors and wrote factor - and once it existed, there probably was no good reason not to include it as a command in subsequent Unix versions. So the "practical uses" of factor may depend on what you consider practical - if you are into prime number theory, it is probably a great tool/game/whatever.

Comment: one could think of 1337 reasons

Answer (score 14):

I know that in at least one case, for me `factor` was helpful in the analysis of a large data file of unknown format.

If you suspect a file has fixed length records, the prime factors of the file's length provide a starting point from which to determine the actual record length.

Answer (score 4):

Most tools are useful to someone. Here's a question from someone who wants to use `factor` to help divide up a large file into optimally-sized chunks.

[Find a "moderately large" divisor of a given number?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245106/find-a-moderately-large-divisor-of-a-given-number)

Answer (score 3):

It will tell you what prime numbers can be multiplied together to get the number you've specified:

e.g `20 = 2 * 2 * 5`

So,

`> factor 20`

You get `20: 2 2 5` as output

If the number was a prime, e.g 19, you will get a `19` only.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of got this from the man page. I was more curious why you would want to do this in a shell script, or similar. How often do people actually need prime roots? I updated the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 3):

I consider this to be the primary practical use:

```
alias primetime='watch -t -n 1 "factor \$(date +%s)"'
```

Comment: Noob to bash, could you explain how to use this? I naively just tried running it in ato.pxeger and got no output.

Comment: It defines an alias called `primetime`. An alias is a way of defining a new command, usually as a shorthand for some longer more complex command that you need to execute frequently. For example, if you frequently use `ls -l`, then you might define an alias for it: `alias ll="ls -l"`. To use it, simply type the new command; in this case, type `primetime`. You can read more about aliases in the Bash manual page, which can be read online by typing `man bash`.

Comment: Actually, I just tried ato.pxeger and it doesn’t give you an interactive bash session, so this is useless there. If you have an OSX or Linux computer, open a terminal and type it in there.

Answer (score 2):

This may be an utility descended from the early days of UNIX, before scientific calculators were cheap, small, and plentiful.

It may have served to allow the developers of the original UNIX to show that the whole thing could do something useful and that it should keep receiving funding.

Comment: It demonstrates none of the features of Unix though as it's purely computational.

Comment: In the early days of Unix, the `roff` typesetter was developed to satisfy the funding requirements of Unix.

Answer (score -1):

Prime numbers play a large role in cryptography, although I know very little about it, I could fathom that they may find it useful for identifying large primes and the like

Comment: `factor` is limited to numbers that fit into an unsigned integer. Best case, that's 64 bits (≤ 18,446,744,073,709,551,615)—but the smallest number you'd reasonably use in e.g., RSA is 2048 bits. IOW, That's much larger than factor can handle. In fact its so much larger, that writing out how many times larger *exceeds the maximum length of a comment*. It's almost 600 digits long (it's 2¹⁹⁸⁴ if you want to calculate it yourself with e.g., `bc`)

Comment: So not useful today, but maybe 35 years ago? Was cryptography using keys with that high of entropy then? Just thought it might be a possible reason it exists.

Comment: No. If factor *can* factor the number (without chugging for many, many years on it), then it is useless for cryptography. Also, I bet factor uses a relatively slow algorithm...

Comment: Told ya I know very little about cryptography. haha

Comment: @derobert at least the version on my machine (8.25) uses libgmp and can factor very large numbers:

`184467440737095516150000000000001: 19 37 227601536870423 1152893543912729
`

Comment: @ViktorDahl Apparently building with gmp is optional, but seems to be done more now... The info page still suggests factor isn't suited for crypto uses: "if you wish to factor large numbers which do
not have small factors (for example, numbers which are the product of
two large primes), other methods are far better."